# What are the pre-requisites (java, scala, sbt version) for RISC-V Torture Test?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, riscv

I have cloned RISC-V Torture Test https://github.com/Lampro-Mellon/riscv-torture from this repo to get vector support, I have followed all the steps mentioned. but when  I run command

> make igentest

I get errors.

> java -Xmx1G -Xss8M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar sbt-launch.jar
> 'testrun/run' OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
> MaxPermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0 Getting org.scala-sbt sbt
> 0.13.8 ...
>
> :: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS      module not found:
> org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8
>
> ==== local: tried
>
> ```
> /home/mazharul/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml
> ```
>
> ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
>
> http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ==== Maven Central: tried
>
> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.pom
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8: not found
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> :::: ERRORS   Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection
> refused)
> url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required
> url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.pom
>
> :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS unresolved
> dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8: not found Error during sbt
> execution: Error retrieving required libraries   (see
> /home/mazharul/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log) Error: Could not
> retrieve sbt 0.13.8 make: *** [Makefile:44: igentest] Error 1

*I understand sbt version is too old, but I don't know which version should be used?
which java version, which scala version and which sbt version?*

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**

Comment: I would start by just changing the **sbt** version to `1.5.5` and **Scala** to `2.11.11` - the **Java** version could be the latest **Java 8** or the latest **Java 11**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think you mean 2.11.12.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, does it work?

Comment: @mazharulislam not sure what you mean? I can't try right now, I suggested you a possible fix. You are the one that should tell us if that worked or not.

Comment: i have solved it. I have used sbt version 1.4.4, scala 2.11.12, java openjdk version "1.8.0_292". It works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I have used sbt version 1.4.4, scala 2.11.12, java openjdk version "1.8.0_292". It works perfectly